# Register access suppresses otherwise possible optimization (avr-gcc)

Tags: c, optimization, embedded, avr, avr-gcc

The following code contains a simple example for e.g. an avr128da32 MCU.
One can access a SFR via the old macros like `VPORTA_DIR` or via a structure mapping like `VPORTA.DIR`.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static uint16_t g; 

int main() {
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        ++g;
//        VPORTA_DIR; // <1> suppresses optimization
        VPORTA.DIR; // <2> OK
    }
}
```

For case `<2>` the load/store to `g` are hoisted/sinked outsie the loop as expected.

But for case `<1>` this does not happen - but the code should be identical.

What does avr-gcc suppress from optimizing in case `<1>`?

Assembly for `<1>`:

```
main:
ldi r24,lo8(20)  ;  ivtmp_4,
.L2:
lds r18,g        ;  g, g
lds r19,g+1      ;  g, g
subi r18,-1      ;  tmp48,
sbci r19,-1      ; ,
sts g,r18        ;  g, tmp48
sts g+1,r19      ;  g, tmp48
in r25,0         ;  vol.1_7, MEM[(volatile uint8_t *)0B]
subi r24,lo8(-(-1))      ;  ivtmp_4,
cpse r24,__zero_reg__    ;  ivtmp_4,
rjmp .L2         ;
ldi r24,0                ;
ldi r25,0                ;
ret
```

Assembly for `<2>`:

```
main:
lds r24,g        ;  g_lsm.6, g
lds r25,g+1      ;  g_lsm.6, g
ldi r18,lo8(20)  ;  ivtmp_2,
.L2:
in r19,0         ;  vol.1_7, MEM[(struct VPORT_t *)0B].DIR
subi r18,lo8(-(-1))      ;  ivtmp_2,
cpse r18,__zero_reg__    ;  ivtmp_2,
rjmp .L2         ;
adiw r24,20      ;  tmp49,
sts g,r24        ;  g, tmp49
sts g+1,r25      ;  g, tmp49
ldi r24,0                ;
ldi r25,0                ;
ret
```

Compilation is done with avr-gcc 12.2 and `-Os`.

Comment: How do you compile and what disassembly do you get from the two different versions?

Comment: Edited question to be more clear.

Comment: I tried it out on avr-gcc online with just some dummy `volatile uint8_t VPORTA_DIR;` and then I can't reproduce 1). Obviously it shouldn't be placing those crappy lds instructions inside the loop. In fact it's strange that it writes to `g` at all since it has internal linkage. Perhaps it somehow suspects that `VPORTA_DIR` is an alias of `g`, but that's a weird assumption.

Comment: You could try `static uint16_t* restrict gptr = &g;` .. `++*gptr` and see if it generates different code, to rule out pointer aliasing being the culprit.

Comment: Tried that, but gives the same missing optimization then in case `<1>`. And for case `<2>` it is ok.

Comment: I'd try to dig up the definition of this `VPORTA_DIR` from the library headers then, because it seems broken.

Comment: `#define VPORTA_DIR  _SFR_MEM8(0x0000)`

Comment: `#define _SFR_MEM8(mem_addr) _MMIO_BYTE(mem_addr)`

Comment: `#define _MMIO_BYTE(mem_addr) (*(volatile uint8_t *)(mem_addr))`

Comment: So, it is actually a simple cast to `volatile`.

Comment: `#define VPORTA              (*(VPORT_t *) 0x0000)`

Comment: `typedef struct VPORT_struct
{
    register8_t DIR;  /* Data Direction */
    register8_t OUT;  /* Output Value */
    register8_t IN;  /* Input Value */
    register8_t INTFLAGS;  /* Interrupt Flags */
} VPORT_t;`

Comment: `typedef volatile uint8_t register8_t;`

Comment: The difference in `<2>´ is accessing the register via a volatile struct member.

Comment: (You should add such details in an edit to the question, not in comments) I can reproduce it with that struct if I compile with `-fno-strict-aliasing`. So I'm guessing it's just because the lib contains undefined behavior with the dirty `(*(VPORT_t *) 0x0000)` cast.

Comment: If I use `-fno-strict-aliasing` I get no optimization in both cases, also with the original code. So, ist this a missing-optimization bug in avr-gcc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to be a library and/or compiler (port) bug and it seems more serious than just a missed optimization. I can reproduce it in avr-gcc 12.2 (and much older) like this:

```
gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Os -mmcu=avr51 -fno-strict-aliasing
```

```c
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct VPORT_struct 
{     
  volatile uint8_t DIR;  /* Data Direction */     
  volatile uint8_t OUT;  /* Output Value */     
  volatile uint8_t IN;  /* Input Value */     
  volatile uint8_t INTFLAGS;  /* Interrupt Flags */ 
} VPORT_t;

#define VPORTA (*(VPORT_t*) 0x0000)

static uint16_t g; 

int main() {
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        ++g;
        VPORTA.DIR;
    }
}
```

Output (completely bananas):

```
__zero_reg__ = 1
main:
        ldi r24,lo8(20)
.L2:
        lds r18,g
        lds r19,g+1
        subi r18,-1
        sbci r19,-1
        sts g+1,r19
        sts g,r18
        lds r25,0
        subi r24,lo8(-(-1))
        cpse r24,__zero_reg__
        rjmp .L2
        ldi r24,0
        ldi r25,0
        ret
```

---

Here the `#define VPORTA (*(VPORT_t*) 0x0000)` (as done in the AVR library according to OP) is a dirty cast which seems to trip the compiler. Somehow it seems to think `VPORT` may be an alias for `g` which is just nonsense. `uint16_t` is not a compatible type with `VPORT_t`. None of the exceptions to the strict aliasing rule applies.

Oddly enough it works while strict aliasing is enabled (which should be the default setting `-fstrict-aliasing`) but not when I disable it `-fno-strict-aliasing`. And yet there's no case for strict aliasing here. With strict aliasing the expected code is generated, along the lines of:

```
.L2:
    lds r19,0
    subi r18,lo8(-(-1))
    cpse r18,__zero_reg__
    rjmp .L2
```

That 0x0000 happens to to be the null pointer constant doesn't seem to matter, I get the same wrong machine code no matter address used. If I do, I get a nonsense warning however:

> warning: array subscript 0 is outside array bounds of 'VPORT_t[0]' {aka 'struct VPORT_struct[]'} [-Warray-bounds] | #define VPORTA (*(VPORT_t*) 0x0001)

The heck? This all just seems completely broken and I can't explain why. Obviously, don't use dirty casts like this, but if that's what you were given from the AVR library, then that library is bad.

Also the compiler should be able to just remove all access to `g` from the code since it isn't used in any expression containing side effects.

---

The obvious work-around is to drop the struct:

```
#define VPORTA_DIR (*(volatile uint8_t*)0x0000u)
```

Comment: Isn't it the other way round? In my case using `VPORTA.DIR` leds to correct optimization but using `VPORTA_DIR` prohibits the optimization (with `-fstrict-aliasing` which is enabled by default).

Comment: @wimalopaan Well I don't have access to the actual library, but this code here is stand-alone without any lib and it results in broken machine code. Casting from an integer to a struct object is strictly speaking not UB but implementation-defined, although in this case it doesn't seem reliable in the slightest. Also the strict aliasing options should not matter at all! But they do.

Comment: For me using the structure mapping with `VPORTA.DIR` is a viable workaround because it makes the optimization possible. And I have no idea why `VPORTA_DIR` is suppressing it.

Comment: Therefore I filed another bug to `gcc`.

Comment: You can silence the waring with `--param=min-pagesize=0 `

Comment: @wimalopaan Well either way it is broken because if you `restrict` qualify a pointer then you tell the compiler "the _only_ access to this object in the whole translation unit is through this pointer". But gcc ignores that too.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108778

Comment: Maybe this one is also related: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108712